# Google Appengine: db.LinkProperty vs db.URLProperty

Tags: google-app-engine

There are many examples of using the property type db.URLProperty in appengine, but it's not listed at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses . Was this deprecated by db.LinkProperty? I can't seem to find docs about the deprecation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLProperty is just an alias for the LinkProperty. Please use either of those. Maybe we shoud document it explicitely.